# Extending an existing product using Eclipse Oomph

Tags: eclipse, oomph

I'd like to create a new product for my own usage which extends Eclipse Neon ( or possibly Oxygen ).

I know that I can manually add update sites and UIs using Oomph, but I would rather like to define a reference to an existing product - like Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers - and then just add some other features on top.

Is that possible using Oomph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done by adding product requirement to the setup

```
<p2:Requirement
    xmi:version="2.0"
    xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI"
    xmlns:p2="http://www.eclipse.org/oomph/p2/1.0"
    name="epp.package.jee"/>
```

Note that you still might need to bring in more features manually, see  [Extending 'Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers' brings in fewer features than expected](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1083214/) for all the details.